# How to load different buttons in a form depending on route using Angular 5

Tags: routes, mean-stack, angular5

I am building a MEAN crud. I display a list of students in my main component StudentsComponent and when I want to edit the information for a specific sutdent I route to StudentFormComponent which loads a form containing all the values in the student object selected.
I also route to the same component StudentFormComponent when I want to add a new student.

How can I display two different buttons one for adding and one for editing, in the same component based on which route led me there:
So my routes look like this:
...

```
{path: 'add, component: 'ModalityFormComponent'},
{path: 'edit/:id', component : 'ModalityFormComponent'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed the single quote ' after  {path :'add'

```
{path: 'add', component: 'ModalityFormComponent'}, {path: 'edit/:id', component : 'ModalityFormComponent'}
```

Comment: I was just typing it out, I didn't copy and paste from my code.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. I was mainly interested in figuring out whether I am adding or editing a form based on the route that led me to the form given that either routes (add or edit) lead to the same form. 
So I got the url segment :

```
const myUrl: Observable<String> = 
    this._route.url.map(segments => segments.join('-')); 
myUrl.subscribe(seg => {this._seg = seg.split('-')[0]; });
```

then in the method where I handled the click event I used the private variable _seg which contained the value either 'add' or 'edit' and acted accordingly.